Coroutines accelerate execution by more times than number of logical processors. Why?
I'm playing around with kotlin coroutines and now I am testing it on Nilakantha series (formula for calculating Pi).
Here is my code:
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlin.system.measureTimeMillis
import kotlin.Long.Companion.MAX_VALUE

const val MEASURE_COUNT = 10
const val ITERATIONS = 1_000_000_000

fun main() {

    val sequentialTime = measureTimeMultiple(ITERATIONS, ::calculatePiNilakanthaSequential, "calculatePiNilakanthaSequential")
    val parallelTime = measureTimeMultiple(ITERATIONS, ::calculatePiNilakanthaParallel, "calculatePiNilakanthaParallel")

    println("Parallelization Speedup: ${sequentialTime.toDouble() / parallelTime}")
}

fun calculatePiNilakanthaSequential(iterations: Int): Double {
    var pi = 3.0
    var sign = 1.0

    for (n in 1..iterations) {
        val numerator = 4.0 * sign
        val denominator = (2.0 * n) * (2.0 * n + 1) * (2.0 * n + 2)
        pi += numerator / denominator
        sign *= -1.0
    }

    return pi
}

fun calculatePiNilakanthaParallel(iterations: Int): Double {
    val cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()
    val chunkSize = iterations / cores

    val results = runBlocking {
        (0 until cores).map { core ->
            async(Dispatchers.Default) {
                val start = core * chunkSize + 1
                val end = if (core == cores - 1) iterations else (core + 1) * chunkSize
                var partialPi = 0.0
                var sign = if (start % 2 == 0) -1.0 else 1.0

                for (n in start..end) {
                    val numerator = 4.0 * sign
                    val denominator = (2.0 * n) * (2.0 * n + 1) * (2.0 * n + 2)
                    partialPi += numerator / denominator
                    sign *= -1.0
                }
                partialPi
            }
        }.awaitAll()
    }

    return 3.0 + results.sum()
}

fun measureTimeMultiple(iterations: Int, function: (Int) -> Any, functionName: String): Long {
    var minTime = MAX_VALUE

    for (i in 1..MEASURE_COUNT) {
        val time = measureTimeMillis {
            function(iterations)
        }
        if (time < minTime) minTime = time
    }

    println("$functionName() took minimum $minTime ms")
    return minTime
}

It gives the following output:
calculatePiNilakanthaSequential() took minimum 4499 ms
calculatePiNilakanthaParallel() took minimum 1003 ms
Parallelization Speedup: 4.485543369890329

My processor is Intel Core i3-1115G4. It has 2 physical and 4 logical cores.
JDK version is 8.
According to Amdahl's law, it is impossible to get an acceleration greater than the number of logical processors. But every time I run this I get more than 4x acceleration.
Why?

Edit:
I thought that maybe kotlin coroutines are somehow more optimized that just plain execution, so I tried creating one coroutine and doing all the work there. It expectedly didn't speed it up, so the answer is probably not in coroutines themselves, but in work partitioning/pipelining/cache? I have no idea

I can confirm a similar behavior in my machine. I did some additional checks: I verified the number of iterations is the same, I tried to check if this could be a JVM optimization, but it doesn't seem so.

I would try the same test with 4 threads as well. I suspect results will be the same. Maybe this is a hardware thing, e.g. CPU increases per-core speed if there is more workload?

@broot he already is running with 4 threads, isn't he?

When I run it on an Intel Core i7 with 4 cores and 8 threads, the parallelization speedup is 2.3 when running on mains and 2.8 when running on batteries. So my results (speedup is less than number of cores) are the opposite of yours.

By the way, when using a series sum to calculate a value, to get a more accurate result you should always add the smallest terms first. Both your sequential and parallel methods add the largest terms first, so when it comes to adding the smaller terms much of the precision is lost. Try printing the calculated value and compare it with kotlin.math.PI.

@k314159 does the speedup change when you increase the number of iterations/decrease it?

No, it doesn't seem to make a difference

@k314159 I changed the order in sequential function according to your advice, tested and compared it to the previous version, and not only did it improve the precision, it also doubled execution speed. So I think this fact is partially the answer as each coroutine had to deal with smaller numbers, therefore ran faster. Now the next part of the question becomes why double addition is slower with bigger numbers. I'll be very grateful if you provide me with resources explaining this. Please extend and post it as an answer.

Also, I compared two variants of new function (adding smaller terms first): 1) with pi set to 3.0 from the beginning and 2) pi initialy set to 0.0 and adding 3.0 in the end. Turned out precision of the 2nd variant was significantly better, but the speedup was somewhere around 1.09 compared to the 1st variant.

That's a good discovery! I expect that adding two doubles together that have the same or similar exponent might be faster than adding two doubles with wildly different exponents. The latter is what you do with your initial sequential method. At some of the later points, you're adding something like n x 10^(-50) to 3.141.... This is my hunch at the moment; I'll see if there's any explanation for that.

What JRE version are you running? I've just discovered that when I run it with JDK 23, the sequential method runs about 3 times faster than when I run it with JDK 21 or earlier. I don't know why the JRE version affects only the sequential method, not the parallel one.

Another thing I'm finding is that, when running under JRE 23, calculating pi using a reverse iteration is slightly slower than the usual forward iteration. On the other hand, running under JRE 21 and earlier, the reverse iteration is faster. So I would guess that it's something to do with the optimization quality of the JIT compiler in each version.

@k314159 Surprising results! I used JRE 21.0.2.

I'm fairly sure that this is due to the JIT compiler analyzing each method differently and making different decisions about how to compile it. The reason I came to that probable conclusion is as follows.
Using Java 21, on my i7 (8-core) machine, I get a parallelization speedup of just over 8. Sometimes as high as 9.
Running without JIT compilation (by setting the environment variable JAVA_OPTS=-Xint) the application runs much slower, and gives a parallelization speedup of about 2.5. Much less than the number of threads used by the coroutines, presumably due to the overhead of managing threads/coroutines in interpreted bytecode.
Now, to make sure that both the sequential and parallel methods run the exact same calculation method in both cases, I changed your code to the following:
fun calculatePiNilakanthaSequential(iterations: Int) =
    3.0 + calculatePiNilakanthaPartial(1, iterations)

fun calculatePiNilakanthaParallel(iterations: Int): Double {
    val cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()
    val chunkSize = iterations / cores

    val results = runBlocking {
        (0 until cores).map { core ->
            async(Dispatchers.Default) {
                val start = core * chunkSize + 1
                val end = if (core == cores - 1) iterations else (core + 1) * chunkSize
                calculatePiNilakanthaPartial(start, end)
            }
        }.awaitAll()
    }

    return 3.0 + results.sum()
}

fun calculatePiNilakanthaPartial(start: Int, end: Int): Double {
    var pi = 0.0
    var sign = if (start % 2 == 0) -1.0 else 1.0

    for (n in start..end) {
        val numerator = 4.0 * sign
        val denominator = (2.0 * n) * (2.0 * n + 1) * (2.0 * n + 2)
        pi += numerator / denominator
        sign *= -1.0
    }

    return pi
}

This way, the method calculatePiNilakanthaPartial is the one that takes the most time, and it's the same method that is called by both calculatePiNilakanthaSequential and calculatePiNilakanthaParallel. If that method gets JIT-compiled, the same compiled code gets run by both parallel and sequential methods.
The result? A parellelization speedup of about 6. A decent speedup given 4 physical, 8 logical cores, but not more than 8.
So, to conclude, it seems that the JIT compiler (in JVM versions 22 or earlier) compiled the calculatePiNilakanthaSequential method suboptimally for some reason. In Java 23, the JIT compiler does a much better job for the sequential method, which runs about 3 times faster, and hence the parallelization speedup is much lower.

See also my related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79250946

I found that just this decomposition of calculatePiNilakanthaSequential somehow made the function almost twice as fast (Java 21).
